# MSTest: CS0117 'Assert' does not contain a definition for 'ThrowsException'

Tags: c#, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm writing some unit tests with MSTest, using C#, MSVS 2015 and .Net 4.6.1.

This line:

```
Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>( () => 
  select.AllSelectedOptions[0]
);
```

Fails with this compile error:

> CS0117 'Assert' does not contain a definition for 'ThrowsException'

My namespace is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` (the default when you create a unit test project in MSVS).

According to the documentation, [Assert.ThrowsException(Action)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.throwsexception?view=mstest-net-1.2.0#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_Assert_ThrowsException__1_System_Action_) should exist.  But I don't see it in Intellisense ... and I'm getting the compile error.

I've tried a couple of different versions of MSVS (MSVS 2015 and MSVS 2019) and a couple of different versions of MSTest.

Q: Any ideas what might be wrong?

---

As Clint said [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60246172/3135317), I need to install [MSTest v2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/upgrade-to-mstest-v2/) from NuGet in order to use `Assert.ThrowsException<T>()` in MSVS 2015.

But after doing this, MSVS isn't finding any of my tests anymore:

MSVS > Test > Run All (or "Test > Debug > All Tests"):

```
------ Discover test started ------
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:01.127375) ==========
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming you comment out this check, do other `Assert.xxx()` calls work? Is `Assert` the actual class from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` or is it by accident a different class named `Assert`? Which version of the library is linked in the "References" section of your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [**MSTest V2**] to be able to **`Assert.ThrowsException`**

Starting with *VS2017*, the in-box *Unit Test* Project templates use only MSTest V2.

Now that you're on *VS2015* you can install this package **MSTest.Test** from *Nuget* but make sure to remove the old test references like `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` before upgrading to this package

*Add > New Test project > Select MSTest project type*

After this you should be able to use `Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(`

*To [discover and execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTgS3.png) tests also ensure to install MSTest.TestAdapter.*

Further [Reading](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/upgrade-to-mstest-v2/)

Comment: Thank you.  It makes sense: both the compile error in MSVS 2015 (MSTest V2 didn't exist yet), and that it also failed in MSVS 2019 (because the project created in MSVS 2019 retained the MSTest V1 dependencies).,  I installed V2.1 from NuGet, deleted the old V1 reference ... and everything now compiles.  Yay!.  NEW PROBLEM: "MSVS > Run all tests" > `Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:01.127375) `.  It's not finding any of the tests anymore :(  I deleted and rebuilt everything from scratch, but still no-go :(  Q: Any suggestions?

Comment: ahh okie, looks like you need to install MSTest.TestAdapter

Comment: Bingo: that was it.  I needed to install two NuGet packages (MSTest.TestFramework v2.1.0 *AND* MSTest.TestAdapter v2.1.0).  Now everything works perfectly.  Thank you!